# FileMaker Pro database structure and extracting data from it in JS

Tags: javascript, highcharts, filemaker

So I recently picked up a project in Filemaker Pro where one of the primary programmers had left. Now I've never used Filemaker in my life, which has left me with some problems.

I'm building a set of graphs per record using highcharts. But I have no idea how to access the data in Filemaker Pro because I don't know how fmp stores the data nor how to retrieve it. The code that was left behind had every single graph hard coded like this:

```
     [Date.UTC("& graph::extract_year & ", "& graph::month_in_Jason & ", "& graph::extract_day & ", "& graph::extract_hour & "),"& graph::CA19_9_1 & "],
     [Date.UTC("& graph::extract_year2 & ", "& graph::month_in_Jason2 & ", "& graph::extract_day2 & ", "& graph::extract_hour2 & "),"& graph::CA19_9_2 & "],
     [Date.UTC("& graph::extract_year3 & ", "& graph::month_in_Jason3 & ", "& graph::extract_day3 & ", "& graph::extract_hour3 & "),"& graph::CA19_9_3 & "],
```

This doesn't really work if the record has more/less datapoints or if there are fields that aren't hard coded.

If possible I'd like to extract the data similar to SQL where I can query a specific column or row and get all the dates/datapoints in an array, or a JSON.

Comment: If you're using FMP v.12 or higher, you can actually use a SQL SELECT statement to query the tables in your solution - see: http://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fexecutesql.html%23wwconnect_header  --- FileMaker's native way is shown in the snippet above: the expression `graph::extract_year` returns the value of the `extract_year` field in the `graph` table occurrence, evaluated from the context of the current record. --- See also: http://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Flist.html%23

Comment: Thanks! That's useful. Do you know where I can find all the table occurrences in the actual FMP program? I'd like to see the actual data. The only method I've found so far is by going to 'specify calculation' from 'Edit Layout' which just lists out everything.

Comment: You can find the entire *structure* under File > Manage > Database. To view the *data*, you need to create a *layout*. --- Please note: (1) FileMaker is not an intuitive application - you will not learn it by trial and error; (2) for basic questions like these, you'd be much better off joining one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform; (3) even in a forum, they will expect you to at least do the tutorial before asking questions; without this you won't be able to understand the answers given to you.